# Python import error with Sublime Text 2 with same PYTHONPATH and Python version as terminal

Tags: python, import, sublimetext2

I just installed gdata with pipinstall

while I can import when starting python from the command line:

```
import gdata.docs.service
```

I get an

```
ImportError: No module named docs.service
```

when I do it with the sublime python build. I realize that on Python.sublime-build I can specify the python version and the PYTHOPATH.

I checkt both and made sure to have both the same as on the command line. I also checked that the folder from where I start the python console does not include gdata. What am I missing?

my PYTHONPATH check:

```
import os
try:
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
   user_paths = []

print user_paths
```

and the Python version check:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

I also checked that $which python is the same path as the "cmd" value in the sublime build config file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer.
The named the file gdata.py and this is why the import gdata.docs.service was resolved with the file itself and could obviously not find "docs" in it.